# Partner Communities and Site Prefix

Tags: static-resources, permission-sets, partner-communities

Good day!

I recently configured a partner community in a salesforce org and I found out that for resources to be working (either for loading or navigation) a site prefix should be appended in url.

The issue now is my colleague created a partner community which is not using the particular site prefix and then everything works on his side.

The question now is how is this possible? Is there any configuration/settings that needs to be done? At first I thought it was in permission sets but it seems it is not. Can someone shed some light regarding this? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Upon investigation, looks like the culprit is a community which does not have a site prefix configured. For clarity, when you create a partner community you will be prompted to enter a community name and optionally append a string to the URL. I refer to that as site prefix.

Anyway here is what is happening. Consider the setup below.

Community_A -> https://some.community.domain/mysiteprefix

Community_B -> https://some.community.domain/

In the event that Community_A triggers a remote call and the site prefix was not included in the target URL, it is as if you are calling Community_B which is a valid call.

The question now is how do we prevent this? Technically this should not be allowed. Is this an existing SF bug?

Comment: can you provide an example of what a site prefix appended to the URL looks like? (it sounds like you are describing the `path` portion of a URL)

Comment: @MarkPond Yup. I am actually talking about a section in the URL. If you create a community, you will be prompted to enter a community name and optionally append a URL(site prefix)

Comment: @MarkPond I updated my post for clarity. Thanks